# Is it possible to create Faraday cage in shape of hemisphere?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

Is it possible to create a Faraday cage in the shape of hemisphere?

My goal is to protect a receiver from one direction but keep receiving signals from opposite direction.

Comment: That's not a Faraday cage, that's a [directional antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_antenna). (And for large gain a shallow parabola will outperform a hemisphere – have a look at a satellite dish.)

Comment: (Further note: Depending on the frequency band and required selectivity, a [Yagi-Uda antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yagi%E2%80%93Uda_antenna) may be much cheaper and easier to construct).

Comment: Thanks @SebastianRiese but in my case I cannot use an external antenna

Comment: The fundamental design principles of directional antennas can also be used on a printed circuit board. With modern techniques you can even do things like multiple antennas driven as a phased array – and of course a metallic case can be used as an integral part of the design (but the sizes needs to be in the right relation to the wave length).

Comment: (But if you don't have a lot of antenna design experiences chances are you can't just guesstimate it – rather you have to try it out, or design it in CAD and simulate the setup.)